# Custom format codes in LO Calc - force MM to stand for month

Tags: libreoffice, format, libreoffice-calc

I need to get `D.MM HH:MM` format in a cell, so for example for `07.02.2017 13:44:47` I want to have `7.02 13:44` displayed. What I get is `7.44 13:44`. I know *why* it happens, but is there any way to force the first MMs to stand for month, not minutes?

Image showing the problem is below; both cells have equal values:

[image: Both cells have equal values]

Using **LibreOffice Calc 5.1.4.2** (build **1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1**) on **Linux Mint 18 x64** with 4.4 kernel. Regional settings: **pl_PL.UTF-8**

Comment: I can't replicate the problem in my LO Calc - with Polish settings. I get the expected results with the given format. So _why_ it happens could be significant. BTW, I tried using `D.MM hh:mm` and LO converted that back to `D.MM HH:MM` anyway. Maybe you can help me create your problem.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver I put some more information as well as the screenshot of the problem in the question. Not sure how can I help more...

Comment: Now I know why mine works and yours doesn't: version. I have LO 5.2.3.3. The problem was known and fixed, "as minute and month have same code `M`, disambiguation have been improved" in [LibreOffice 5.2: Release Notes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.2#Number_Format). If you can update to Ver 5.2 it looks like you won't have that problem anymore. In addition several functions were improved or added that make Calc more inter-operable with XLS and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice 5.2 fixed, or enhanced, many things in Calc. Among these is your problem. The [LibreOffice 5.2 Release Notes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.2#Number_Format) says, "as minute and month have same code `M`, disambiguation have been improved." Updating from v5.1.4.2 to something in the v5.2 release set should fix the issue of date/time formats in your sheets.